# skipping 2 lines that comes back periodically when parsing javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, parsing

I'm trying to parse a document that contains 500 times this snippet of 258 lines:

```
256 (first line)
Atoms. Timestep: 66000 
1 0.702825 2.71217 2.71612 
1 16.9592 2.64886 6.79019 
1 0.681418 2.68359 10.8911 
1 16.96 2.6822 14.9396 
1 0.659922 6.77858 2.72442 
1 16.9873 6.7709 6.77907 
1 0.676686 6.76797 10.8581 
...  
1 16.9295 6.74348 14.9315 (258th line)
```

So i'm trying to ignore the first two lines that come back periodically, as to only have the values i want in the array. here is my code for it:

```
fetch('Petit_film_256_atomes.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => { 
    var lineStart = 0;
    var lineEnd = 258;
    for (var j = lineStart; j < lineEnd; j++) {
        const positions = text.split('\n')
            .map(line => line.trim())
            .slice(2)
            .map(line => line.split(' ')) 
            .map(([size, x, y, z]) => ({ 
              size: Number(size), 
              x: Number(x), 
              y: Number(y), 
              z: Number(z)
             }));
    }
    lineStart += 258;
    lineEnd += 258;
});
```

I thought using the lineStart and lineEnd variables the first two lines every 258 lines can be cut using slice(2), but only the first two lines of the whole document are cut. How do i make the slice repeat itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
const size = 258;
let result = [];
fetch('Petit_film_256_atomes.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((input) => {
        // put every line into the array
        const arr = input.split('\n')
            .map(line => line.trim())

        while (arr.length > 0)
            result.push(
                arr
                .splice(0, size) // split the array into chunks of length 258
                .slice(2) // remove the first two lines of every array
                .map(line => { 
                    const [size, x, y, z] = line.split(' ').map(Number)
                    return { size, x, y, z }
                })
            );
    })
```

Comment: thank you, except now every single line is mapped as a value... how do i map result as a 2D array in which result[i][j].size = 1, result[i][j].x = 0.702825, result[i][j].y = 2.71217... etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing too much looping over the same text by using a modulo operator:

```
fetch('Petit_film_256_atomes.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => { 
    var lineStart = 0
    var lineEnd = 258
    text = text.split('\n')
    const positions = []
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
         // push a new array every 258 iterations
         if (i % 258 === 0) positions.push([])
         // skip the first two lines
         if (i % 258 < 2) continue
         const [size, x, y, z] = text[i].trim().split(' ').map(Number)
         positions[positions.length - 1].push({ size, x, y, z })
    }
});
```